# Reactjs if condition jsx

Tags: reactjs

```
  const [grouppermission, SetGrpPermissions] =useState([]);

  const Group = async () => {
    const response = await userModulePermission("20",_UsersId);
    console.log("responseGROUP: ", response.data)
    SetGrpPermissions(response.data.map(user => ({
          udf_Users_IsHaveModuleAccess:user.udf_Users_IsHaveModuleAccess
        })))
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    Group();
  }, [reRender]);
```

this is the result

[image]

this is where the if condition , i just want that if the udf_Users_IsHaveModuleAccess is 0 then it will not createElement and if 1 then it will create.

```
    {grouppermission[0].udf_Users_IsHaveModuleAccess &&
        <CCreateElement
        items={groupperms}
        components={{
          CSidebarNavDivider,
          CSidebarNavDropdown,
          CSidebarNavItem,
          CSidebarNavTitle
        }}
      />
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to put ?

```
{grouppermission[0]?.udf_Users_IsHaveModuleAccess !== 0 &&
        <CCreateElement
        items={groupperms}
        components={{
          CSidebarNavDivider,
          CSidebarNavDropdown,
          CSidebarNavItem,
          CSidebarNavTitle
        }}
      />
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is if not zero then create it:

```
{grouppermission[0].udf_Users_IsHaveModuleAccess !== 0 &&
        <CCreateElement
        items={groupperms}
        components={{
          CSidebarNavDivider,
          CSidebarNavDropdown,
          CSidebarNavItem,
          CSidebarNavTitle
        }}
      />
    }
```

Or if you want to be explicit about it being 1:

```
{grouppermission[0].udf_Users_IsHaveModuleAccess === 1 &&
        <CCreateElement
        items={groupperms}
        components={{
          CSidebarNavDivider,
          CSidebarNavDropdown,
          CSidebarNavItem,
          CSidebarNavTitle
        }}
      />
    }
```

I prefer to do conditional rendering inside a function.
Assuming this is a function component:

```
const RenderCCreateElement = ():JSX.Element => {
      if(grouppermission[0].udf_Users_IsHaveModuleAccess === 0){
            return (<React.Element />);
      }

      if(grouppermission[0].udf_Users_IsHaveModuleAccess === 1){
            return (
              <CCreateElement
            items={groupperms}
            components={{
              CSidebarNavDivider,
              CSidebarNavDropdown,
              CSidebarNavItem,
              CSidebarNavTitle
            }}
          />
            );
      }

     return (<React.Element />);
};
```

The you can call it for example like this:

```
<div>{RenderCCreateElement()}</div>
```

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'udf_Users_IsHaveModuleAccess')`

Comment: 0 is also a false thought.

Comment: @katio that is a different issue altogether

Answer (score 0):

**Look like you have some typo and you will need to check if it's an empty array first**

```
{
  grouppermission[0]?.udf_Users_IsHaveModuleAccess && (  //<-- Add optional chaining here
    <CreateElement   // <-- CCreateElement is this a typo?
      items={groupperms}
      components={{
        CSidebarNavDivider,
        CSidebarNavDropdown,
        CSidebarNavItem,
        CSidebarNavTitle
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The value you are checking with either be `0` or `1`? Simple check for truthy will work in this case.

```
!!grouppermission[0].udf_Users_IsHaveModuleAccess &&
```